# Communication between laptop & Android mobile in LAN

Tags: android, networking

I am developing an Android app which is having sent the data collected from mobile have to sent to the laptop/desktop. But I have no idea how to send in LAN?

Avoiding web service, is there any way to sent the data to system in LAN?

Answer (score 1):

yes, we can send data over TCP/IP sockets.
This application might have two applications:(1) Desktop Application, (2) Mobile Application

1. Create Desktop application, create a ServerSocket in the app, listening on some port.
2. Create mobile application. Create a Socket in this app, to the ip of desktop and socket, ServerSocket is listening.
3. By Mobile app send data to the socket, by writing in output stream, from socket.
4. In Desktop application, read the input stream, parse the stream, and save data.